# error 3012 access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Basically I have this code and I get a error 3012 query already exists.  What can I do here?

```
Public Function KSMSTransferKSMS()
Dim bfile As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim myQueryName As String
Dim myExportFileName As String
Dim sqlString1 As String
Dim sqlString2 As String
Dim sqlString3 As String
Dim sqlString4 As String
Dim sqlString As String
Dim MyValue As Variant
Dim WarehouseCode As String
Dim Country As String
Dim CustomerAction As String
Dim rsExport As DAO.QueryDef
Dim Db As Database

'On Error GoTo Handler:

MyValue = InputBox("Account Name", "Enter Account Name")

Set dbs = CurrentDb

WarehouseCode = "w*"
Country = "US"
CustomerAction = ""

sqlString1 = "SELECT [Account Assignments Table].[Account #], [Account Assignments Table].[Account Name], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Company Name], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].Code, [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Phone1], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Address1], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Address2], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Department/Floor], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location City], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location State/Province], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Zip/Postal Code], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Country], '" & CustomerAction & "' AS [Customer Action] "
sqlString2 = "FROM [Account Assignments Table] RIGHT JOIN [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table] ON [Account Assignments Table].[Account #] = [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Account Number] "
sqlString3 = "GROUP BY [Account Assignments Table].[Account #], [Account Assignments Table].[Account Name], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Company Name], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].Code, [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Phone1], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Address1], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Address2], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Department/Floor], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location City], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location State/Province], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Zip/Postal Code], [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Country], '" & CustomerAction & "' "
sqlString4 = "HAVING ((([Account Assignments Table].[Account #]) Is Not Null) AND (([Account Assignments Table].[Account Name])='" & MyValue & "') AND (([Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].Code) Like '" & WarehouseCode & "') AND (([Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table].[Current Location Country])='" & Country & "'))"
sqlString = sqlString1 & sqlString2 & sqlString3 & sqlString4

Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlString)

bfile = "S:\_Reports\KSMS\Designated Letter\KSMS Designated Letter - "

Set rsExport = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQueryDef", sqlString)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "rsExport", bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls", False, _
    "KSMS Designated Letter"

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete myExportQueryDef
Set Db = Nothing

Exit Function
```

I need to know what I need to do in the current set of code what code I need to put in where to make this error go away.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to delete the query: `CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "myExportQueryDef"`

However if the query doesn't exist that will error so might want code that first checks if the query exists. One way:
`If Not IsNull(DLookup("[Name]", "mySysObjects", "[Name]='myExportQueryDef'")) Then`

Instead of deleting and recreating the object, change its SQL property.

```
Dim qd As QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDef("myExportQueryDef")
...
qd.SQL = sqlString
```

Instead of code that routinely changes db design, I recommend exporting a report instead of query whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not changing the structural components (i.e., tables, fields, joins) of query, but passing values, consider using [QueryDef paramaterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) which requires no re-creation of query. As an aside, *parameterization* is a programming industry best practice across all databases and especially since you actually take in user input. A clever, hacker/user can [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) you and destroy your database or retrieve confidential information! Plus with this approach, there is no need to worry about quotes or concatenating VBA strings.

And because you need data exported to Excel by parameter values, consider creating a temp table that is regularly dropped and created. Yes, this is slightly more overhead than a query drop/create but arguably more secure. Below is SQL syntax for a stored query that defines placeholder parameters and then in VBA after assigning the querydef, you bind VBA values to placeholders.

**SQL** Make-Table Action Query *(save query only once; table aliases are used for less wordy code)*

```sql
PARAMETERS CustomerActionParam Text(255), AccountNameValue TEXT(255), 
           WarehouseParam TEXT(255), CountryParam TEXT(255);
SELECT a.[Account #], a.[Account Name], p.[Company Name], p.Code, 
       p.[Current Location Phone1], p.[Current Location Address1], 
       p.[Current Location Address2], p.[Current Location Department/Floor], 
       p.[Current Location City], p.[Current Location State/Province], 
       p.[Current Location Zip/Postal Code], p.[Current Location Country], 
       [CustomerActionParam] AS [Customer Action] 
INTO mytmpTable

FROM [Account Assignments Table] a 
RIGHT JOIN [Post Sales RTM Known Shipper Table] p ON a.[Account #] = p.[Account Number] 

WHERE (((a.[Account #]) Is Not Null) AND ((a.[Account Name])= [AccountNameValue]) 
   AND ((p.Code) Like [WarehouseParam]) AND ((p.[Current Location Country])=[CountryParam]))

GROUP BY a.[Account #], a.[Account Name], p.[Company Name], p.Code, 
         p.[Current Location Phone1], p.[Current Location Address1], 
         p.[Current Location Address2], p.[Current Location Department/Floor], 
         p.[Current Location City], p.[Current Location State/Province], 
         p.[Current Location Zip/Postal Code], p.[Current Location Country], 
         [CustomerActionParam]
```

**VBA**  *(assign Querydef and bind parameters)*

```vb
Dim dbs As Database
Dim tbldef As TableDef, qdef As QueryDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb

' DELETE TEMP TABLE IF EXISTS
For Each tbldef in dbs.TableDefs
   If tbldef.Name = "myTempTable" then
      dbs.Execute "DROP TABLE myTempTable", dbFailOnError
   End if
Next tbldef

MyValue = InputBox("Account Name", "Enter Account Name")

' ASSIGN SAVED QUERY
Set qdef = dbs.QueryDefs("myQuery")

' BIND PARAMETERS
qdef!CustomerActionParam = ""
qdef!AccountNameValue = MyValue
qdef!WarehouseParam = "w*"
qdef!CountryParam = "US"

' EXECUTE ACTION TO CREATE TEMP TABLE
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

' EXPORT TEMP TABLE TO EXCEL
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "myTempTable", _
    bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls", False, "KSMS Designated Letter"

Set tbldef = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: I went ahead and did the following:

Comment: On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "myExportQueryDef"

Comment: DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "myExportQueryDef", bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls", False, _
        "KSMS Designated Letter"

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "myExportQueryDef"

Comment: So obviously, you didn't need my solution.=) You actually don't even need to recreate a temp table but can use same table with data cleaned out and appended according to param values with a delete/append query pair. Even less overhead. Good luck and happy coding!